# The argument type ' ' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData?' - How can I use different custom icons for each index?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new in Flutter. So I have downloaded some custom icons from https://www.fluttericon.com/
I can use them manually for sure, there is no problem. But how can I use them for each index item in groceryItems?

**categories.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:shopping_list/models/category.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/presentation/my_flutter_app_icons.dart';

const categories = {
  Categories.vegetables: Category(
    'Vegetables',
    Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 255, 128),
    Icon(MyFlutterApp.carrot)
  ),
  Categories.fruit: Category(
    'Fruit',
    Color.fromARGB(255, 145, 255, 0),
    Icon(MyFlutterApp.apple_alt)
  ),
  Categories.meat: Category(
    'Meat',
    Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 102, 0),
    Icon(MyFlutterApp.meat)
  ),
  Categories.dairy: Category(
    'Dairy',
    Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 208, 255),
    Icon(MyFlutterApp.cheese)
  ),
  Categories.carbs: Category(
    'Carbs',
    Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 60, 255),
    Icon(MyFlutterApp.toast)
  ),
  Categories.sweets: Category(
    'Sweets',
    Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 149, 0),
    Icon(MyFlutterApp.candy_cane)
  ),
  Categories.spices: Category(
    'Spices',
    Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 187, 0),
    Icon(MyFlutterApp.leaf)
  ),
  Categories.convenience: Category(
    'Convenience',
    Color.fromARGB(255, 191, 0, 255),
    Icon(MyFlutterApp.local_convenience_store)
  ),
  Categories.hygiene: Category(
    'Hygiene',
    Color.fromARGB(255, 149, 0, 255),
    Icon(MyFlutterApp.hands_wash)
  ),
  Categories.other: Category(
    'Other',
    Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 225, 255),
    Icon(MyFlutterApp.shop)
  ),
};
```

**dummy_items.dart**

```
import 'package:shopping_list/models/category.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/models/grocery_item.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/data/categories.dart';

final  groceryItems = [
  GroceryItem(
      id: 'a',
      name: 'Milk',
      quantity: 1,
      category: categories[Categories.dairy]!),
  GroceryItem(
      id: 'b',
      name: 'Bananas',
      quantity: 5,
      category: categories[Categories.fruit]!),
  GroceryItem(
      id: 'c',
      name: 'Beef Steak',
      quantity: 1,
      category: categories[Categories.meat]!),
];
```

**grocery_list.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/data/dummy_items.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/presentation/my_flutter_app_icons.dart';

class GroceryList extends StatelessWidget {
  const GroceryList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Your groceries',
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: groceryItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ListTile(
            title: Text(
              groceryItems[index].name,
            ),
            leading: Container(
              width: 28,
              height: 28,
              color: groceryItems[index].category.color,
              child:  const Icon(
                  MyFlutterApp(groceryItems[index].category.icon), //this is where I try to fix
              ),
            ),
            trailing: Text(
              groceryItems[index].quantity.toString(),
            ),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my first question here. Will be glad if you can help!

Answer (score 0):

The `icon` is already an `Icon` and you try to wrap it in another `Icon`. I also have no idea why you also wrap it in `MyFlutterApp`. I believe you simply need to replace

```
child:  const Icon(
                  MyFlutterApp(groceryItems[index].category.icon), //this is where I try to fix
              ),
```

with

```
child: groceryItems[index].category.icon,
```